# What are the differences between the {before_,}{install,script} .travis.yml options?

Tags: travis-ci

Inside the `.travis.yml` configuration file what is the practical difference between `before_install`, `install`, `before_script` and `script` options?

I have found no documentation explaining the differences between these options.

Comment: You did look here ? https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/

Comment: Yes, and except for the difference between "errored" and "failed", there is no explanation for what is the difference between `before_install`, `install` and `before_script`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You don't need to use these sections, but if you do, you communicate the intent of what you're doing:

```
before_install:
  # execute all of the commands which need to be executed 
  # before installing dependencies
  - composer self-update
  - composer validate

install:
  # install all of the dependencies you need here
  - composer install --prefer-dist

before_script:
  # execute all of the commands which need to be executed 
  # before running actual tests
  - mysql -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE test'
  - bin/doctrine-migrations migrations:migrate

script:
  # execute all of the commands which 
  # should make the build pass or fail
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
  - vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --verbose --diff --dry-run
```

See, for example, https://github.com/localheinz/composer-normalize/blob/0.8.0/.travis.yml.

Comment: I still don't understand why in https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/, the `docker build` command is put on `before_install` step. Shouldn't it be in `install` step?

Comment: @PahleviFikriAuliya As far as I understand it in the context of the example, `docker build` is used to set up the test environment - if that is needed before dependencies can be installed, then it makes sense to move this to the `before_install` section, otherwise maybe the `before_script` section would be more appropriate. Looking at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/#Bundler I understand that docker shouldn't be necessary for installing dependencies.

Answer (score 23):

The difference is in the state of the job when something goes wrong.

Git 2.17 (Q2 2018) illustrates that in [commit 3c93b82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c93b82920506a62ebdf3b6453d91b44aae0be97) (08 Jan 2018) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c710d18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c710d182ea6d3846f6f2dc6f1b6c7dbd35c2fce8), 08 Mar 2018)</sup>

That illustrates the practical difference between `before_install`, `install`, `before_script` and `script` options

> ### `travis-ci`: build Git during the '`script`' phase
>
> Ever since we started building and testing Git on Travis CI ([522354d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/522354d70f4fab744f25bc3d641b478584bbfc3b): Add Travis CI support, 2015-11-27, Git v2.7.0-rc0), we build Git in the
>   '`before_script`' phase and run the test suite in the '`script`' phase
>   (except in the later introduced 32 bit Linux and Windows build jobs,
>   where we build in the '`script`' phase').
>
> Contrarily, the Travis CI practice is to build and test in the
>   '`script`' phase; indeed Travis CI's default build command for the
>   '`script`' phase of C/C++ projects is:
>
> ```
> ./configure && make && make test
> ```
>
> The reason why Travis CI does it this way and why it's a better
>   approach than ours lies in how unsuccessful build jobs are
>   categorized.  After something went wrong in a build job, its state can
>   be:
>
> - **'failed'**, if a command in the '`script`' phase returned an error.
>     This is indicated by a red 'X' on the Travis CI web interface.
> - **'errored'**, if a command in the '`before_install`', '`install`', or
>     '`before_script`' phase returned an error, or the build job exceeded
>     the time limit.
>     This is shown as a red '!' on the web interface.
>
> This makes it easier, both for humans looking at the Travis CI web
>   interface and for automated tools querying the Travis CI API, to
>   decide when an unsuccessful build is our responsibility requiring
>   human attention, i.e. when a build job 'failed' because of a compiler
>   error or a test failure, and when it's caused by something beyond our
>   control and might be fixed by restarting the build job, e.g. when a
>   build job 'errored' because a dependency couldn't be installed due to
>   a temporary network error or because the OSX build job exceeded its
>   time limit.
>
> The drawback of building Git in the '`before_script`' phase is that one
>   has to check the trace log of all 'errored' build jobs, too, to see
>   what caused the error, as it might have been caused by a compiler
>   error.
>   This requires additional clicks and page loads on the web interface and additional complexity and API requests in automated tools.
>
> Therefore, move building Git from the '`before_script`' phase to the
>   '`script`' phase, updating the script's name accordingly as well.
>   '`ci/run-builds.sh`' now becomes basically empty, remove it.
>   Several of our build job configurations override our default '`before_script`' to do nothing; with this change our default '`before_script`' won't do
>   anything, either, so remove those overriding directives as well.